# Avoid rate limit for changing voice channel name discord js 13

Tags: discord.js

I'm trying to create a slash command using discord.js v13 to change the names of voice channels. I am using this code to do this :

```js
module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('name')
        .setDescription('Set name for your voice channel')
        .addStringOption(option => option.setName('name').setDescription('Enter your name').setRequired(true)),
    async execute(interaction) {
        const name = interaction.options.getString('name');
        if (!interaction.member.voice.channel) await interaction.reply('Error not in a voice channel!');
        else {
            await interaction.member.voice.channel.setName(name);
            await interaction.reply('Done!');
        }
    },
};
```

This code is fine and makes the job done. But as you know I can change the voice channel's name only 2 times per 10 minutes because of the limit rate. So if a user tries to change the voice channel's name for the third time, I won't get any error on the console, and discord js will queue this request for later and will do it after 10 minutes. But the user gets this error on discord: `This interaction failed`.

I want to check if there was a rate limit for my request, and if is, don't send the request and just reply to the user. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

There is no inherent functionality that is able to handle the situation in the way you want it to, but the problem is soluble using regular old JavaScript. For example, you could use an integer to indicate how many times the command has been used and use setTimeout() to decrement it 10 minutes after the command was called. That way you can check if the int is equal to 2 in which case you skip the .setName().

There are undoubtedly other ways to implement the same or similar behavior, but, to answer your question, unfortunately the discordjs/voice library does not provide any simple way to do it.